# Why can't access keep up with my VBA code in regards to building tables in access from existing xml files using vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The situation more in depth:

I am dealing with around one million existing xml files and I have created a program in `VBA`, within Access 2016 that converts these files to a different type of xml with a new file name, and then saves them to the new file name in a different folder.

As the program builds these new files it also adds entries to about 15 access tables within the database in which the VBA code for the program exists.
The only issue that I am having is that as my code increments the new file name and attempts to add it to the main access table, access "hangs up" and repeats several random increment numbers, a random amount of times which ruins the talbe output and does not allow repeated new file names to save (or they save over the original).

Each time I run the program the result is different, but when I put a stop in my code after the completion of each file conversion and creation and manually cycle through each files by hitting play and refreshing the table with the increment problem, the increment in my talbe works perfect and the results are consistent.

I guess what I am asking is, is it normal for when using VBA code to build tables from existing files, for access to "hang up" when adding a new record to a table using an incrementor?

If not, could I add a refresh of the table after I add a new record entry or before I save the new file to alleviate the issue, and how do I code that refesh  of a table?  (I already use .Update upon the completion of .AddNew)

Or, could I add a pause in similiar locations to allow access to catch up before VBA continues its calculations and processing?

Comment: Without seeing the code - which I suspect is extensive from your description, I wonder if this is a "object left open" type problem which is gobbling memory eventually causing Access to hang. Sometime a DoEvents in a suitable place can force background events to process in a more orderly fashion.

Comment: Again, some representative code and database structure (and some sample data) would help us. However, could you please clarify whether you're creating new tables, or populating existing ones? Your question mentions both.

Comment: Are you saying the "object left open" is the new file I create after converting each original xml file? If this is the case is there anyway to close a created textfile(in the script) after creating it?   I specified textfile because I my program creates textfiles, that upon the dataset completion, I batch rename to xml.

Comment: Always populating existing tables.  Just creating new records in multiple tables.

Comment: And to add to Minty's suspicions, I also believe that problem lies within the usage of memory and its affects on my machine's computing ability.  The representative code does not matter at this point, but as a general overview of what my codes does in relationship to the problem I am describing, I will lay it out below in a sort flow chart.

Comment: In a loop,
Take in the next existing XML file,
Parse it,
Convert it,
Add it to the Tables as the next incremented new file,
Save It,
repeat 1 million times (for each existing file)

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot post your code, or some variation of it? It should not really be that extensive based on what it is doing, a relatively simple `recordset` movement and single increment with a file parser isn't really huge. I can tell you for sure, that no one can solve this problem without more information than is currently being shared. It certainly seems to me that there is a bug in the code somewhere though. In answer to your "question", Access will hang with any sort of looping process no matter how trivial, but it won't affect the way anything is processed in the least.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me how I figured it out but through your answers, talking to colleagues, searching for related questions, and redefining the meaning of life, I found the answer!

The problem was not with my code but with how fast my system executed the code compared to how fast Access executed the .Update function.  My program was getting ahead of the completion of Access's .Update table function to a point where my incrementor would "hang up" and not see the new table entry because it was not there yet.

I added a few millisecond pause after the .Update and poof, perfectly working incrementor and table updating combo.  I will be narrowing the delay time down to the minimum needed shortly, but my question is answered; Access program processing is slower than VBA code calculations by a lot.  Thanks Everyone!